# Can't figure out how to add fade effect

Tags: javascript, html, image, fade

how can i add fade  to this code ??
im trying to make it look like something similar to this

http://jsfiddle.net/xmLk4/
i tried the code in it but i dont know how to add it correctly .

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var slideimages = new Array() // create new array to preload images
slideimages[0] = new Image() // create new instance of image object
slideimages[0].src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fd/000080_Navy_Blue_Square.svg/2000px-000080_Navy_Blue_Square.svg.png"
// set image object src property to an image's src, preloading that image in the process
slideimages[1] = new Image()
slideimages[1].src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/Red.svg/120px-Red.svg.png"
slideimages[2] = new Image()
slideimages[2].src = "http://static.tumblr.com/674bc8c8a561428e14d7c5abe10d696f/ijaflyo/IdQmnirks/tumblr_static_greenbox.png"
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="firstcar.gif" id="slide" width="948" height="403" />

 <script type="text/javascript">

 //variable that will increment through the images
var step=0

function slideit(){
//if browser does not support the image object, exit.
if (!document.images)
return
document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
if (step<2)
 step++
 else
 step=0
//call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
 setTimeout("slideit()",2500)



 }

 slideit()

</script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: At first glance, you're missing some semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are you actually asking.

Do you mean CSS transitions? If so, consider adding

transition:all 0.6s;

You can add it in your `img style= "transition:all 0.6s;"`

Try this now

```
    function slideit(){

   if (!document.images)
      return


        document.getElementById('slide').style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src;
        document.getElementById('slide').style.opacity = "1";
    },500)

        if (step<2)
         step++
         else
         step=0

         setTimeout(slideit,2500)



 }
```

Comment: what im asking is i want to have a fade like this one here:http://jsfiddle.net/xmLk4/

Comment: also what is this code for and where do i add it transition:all 0.6s;

Comment: almost there :) but the fade is slow but the pictures are going to fast.

Comment: one more question! how can i add buttons that moves with every picture?? so for each picture, there is a button to send you to a link??